# Bind ports for intercontainer communication using Docker and Java TestContainers

Tags: java, linux, docker, testcontainers

I'm using Java TestContainers to run two containers - simple OpenLiberty server and MySQL database. I use `network` to put them into 1 network. I create them with the following code:

```java
@ClassRule
public static Network network = Network.newNetwork();

@Container
public static MySQLContainer<?> mysqlDb = new MySQLContainer<>()
            .withDatabaseName("DBNAME")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("pswd")
            .withExposedPorts(3306)
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(443), new ExposedPort(3306))))
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases("testDb");

@Container
public static ApplicationContainer app = new ApplicationContainer("test")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .dependsOn(mysqlDb)
            .withAppContextRoot("/backend")
            .withReadinessPath("/")
            .withHttpPort(9080)
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .withFileSystemBind("/root/.m2", "/root/.m2")
            .withEnv(envVariables);
```

After creation I can check everything is correct by executing `docker container ls`. Also after executing `docker container inspect 'id'` I'm sure they're in the same network with proper aliases.

```
sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                    NAMES
a540e22c9543   test:latest                 "/usr/local/bin/mvn-…"   25 minutes ago   Up 25 minutes   0.0.0.0:32772->9080/tcp, :::32772->9080/tcp              sweet_goldstine
73a2ff3460c4   mysql:5.7.34                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 minutes ago   Up 25 minutes   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->3306/tcp, :::443->3306/tcp   flamboyant_tu
89993b13a2c5   testcontainers/ryuk:0.4.0   "/bin/ryuk"              25 minutes ago   Up 25 minutes   0.0.0.0:32770->8080/tcp, :::32770->8080/tcp              testcontainers-ryuk-c7ccfb4f-cc3b-42d2-b602-fe7f62472a9d
```

In code above you can see that I was forcibly binding internal port 3306 to host port 443. I was doing that because I thought that containers communicate using same ports as host does. And I need for `app` container to use port 443 (It is using external library for database communication, which I'm forced to use, which uses 443 to connect to DB server) to communicate with `mysqlDb`.

But by executing the following code I discovered(I didn't really know this) that docker containers communicate with each other by using exposed ports directly(9080 and 3306) but not bind ports(443 and 32772).

```bash
~$ sudo docker container exec -it 73a2ff3460c4 telnet a540e22c9543 9080
Trying 172.19.0.3...
Connected to a540e22c9543.

~$ sudo docker container exec -it 73a2ff3460c4 telnet a540e22c9543 32772
Trying 172.19.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

~$ sudo docker container exec -it a540e22c9543 telnet 73a2ff3460c4 443
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

~$ sudo docker container exec -it a540e22c9543 telnet 73a2ff3460c4 3306
Connected to 73a2ff3460c4
```

My question is: Can I specify via TestContainers the ports Docker containers will use to communicate with each other, so `app` will send to `mysqlDb:443` and request will be redirected to `mysqlDb:3306` inside container

Comment: Connections between containers _always_ use the "standard" ports and _never_ use the published ports.  I don't think there's a way to remap the ports for connections between containers.  It seems odd to me that an application would expect to use the standard HTTPS port to communicate with a non-HTTP MySQL server, and that the host and port number wouldn't be configurable; can you fix this?

Comment: Nope, the container of the APP and the container of MySQL are in the same network that you created above. So they can see the other through the exposed ports. App can see the MySQL 3306 port. When you bind the container port to a port of your host, it means you are connected a port in your host to a container port. So, from localhost you need to call the bound port, which is in your local network, e.g.: localhost:443 This request goes from your local network to the docker network using a bridge, translating the port from your local network (443) to the docker (mysql:3306) redirecting

Comment: to the container mysql.
So, in the example you post you have the app and database in the docker network. You cannot configure the app to use localhost:443, because in the docker network that means app's container port 443. 
So you need to pass a config to ensure the app connect to the database pointing to the mysql container and the port 3306. You can add a alias to the container (or use one of the generated by testcontainer) and use <alias>:3306 as the database address

Comment: Thanks for ideas and answers. Maybe indeed I should find a way for app to use a standard port 3306. I know it's strange it uses 443 and I don't know why myself, but that's a work project and I don't have expertise to complain on it's architecture